# How to interpret 'xxd' command output

Tags: terminal, binary

So, favouring the command `xxd -b filename` over `hexdump -C filename` to get the actual 1s and 0s of a binary file, i get this output from a file:

```
00009f6: 00000000 00000000 00001100 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00009fc: 01100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011000 00000000  `.....
0000a02: 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000a08: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000a0e: 00000001 00000000 00101111 01010011 01111001 01110011  ../Sys
0000a14: 01110100 01100101 01101101 00101111 01001100 01101001  tem/Li
0000a1a: 01100010 01110010 01100001 01110010 01111001 00101111  brary/
0000a20: 01000110 01110010 01100001 01101101 01100101 01110111  Framew
0000a26: 01101111 01110010 01101011 01110011 00101111 01000011  orks/C
0000a2c: 01101111 01110010 01100101 01010111 01001100 01000001  oreWLA
0000a32: 01001110 00101110 01100110 01110010 01100001 01101101  N.fram
0000a38: 01100101 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101011 00101111  ework/
0000a3e: 01010110 01100101 01110010 01110011 01101001 01101111  Versio
```

Now the binary itself is not a problem, it looks to be hexadecimal which is fairly simple to decode, however, can anyone identify what these non binary columns signify? I assume that the columns 2 to 7 are the actual binary of the file, which leaves columns 1 and 8 which are definitely not binary, but have no stated purpose either as in no column headings.

**So can anyone tell me what the columns on the other side of the binary are for and what they are telling me?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first column reflects the address/position of the data within the file (on the first line of your output it should start with `0000000` unless you have used `xxd -s`), the last column contains the textual representation of the file content (for bytes which have a printable ASCII value).